# Possible to batch WolframAlpha queries?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Sometimes I want some country data not available from `CountryData`. And issuing things like:

```
WolframAlpha[ToString[#]<>" | whatever data", 
             {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}
            ]&/@CountryData["Countries"]
```

is both incredibly slow and I'm sure to hit my daily API limit.

Can I do all these requests in one go?

Comment: This does not help with W|A specifically, but I wanted to mentioned [asynchronous tasks](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AsynchronousTasks.html) (new in v9) if you haven't seen it yet.  It makes parallel downloads possible (which would still not help with the API limit if one would use with W|A, but it would at least speed things up).